# Jquery Ui DatePicker, attaches to textbox but only works once, then all click events are disabled

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#date').datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%--<form id="form1" runat="server">--%>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="date" />
    </div>
    <%--</form>--%>
</body>
</html>
```

I've attached a datepicker to a text box and the first time I click it, it works a treat and populates the text box with the current date. It works fine in IE7 Comp mode, Chrome and Firefox. It works once or twice on IE8 but locks the browser up after that. One interesting note is the host operating system is Windows 2008 R2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not to be snide--can your site survive without compat mode?

Comment: Do the jQuery datepicker demo pages work for you?

Comment: Do you have other javascript on the page? If there is an obscure syntax error somewhere IE will tend to fall over before chrome/ff - try run your js (including plugins) through http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: Compatibility mode, isn't an option as there are some users that use IE7 that can't upgrade (Group policy).

The DatePicker demo pages are doing the same, that's interesting wonder if anything to do with windows server 2008 R2

I've removed all other javascript from the page.

Comment: I've stripped as much content from the page as possible now, and now it only exhibits the behaviour when the page is NOT running in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a corrupt download that I had somehow grabbed from UI, all sorted.